# Question about Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

I have a seemingly trivial question regarding conditional expectation. Consider $x$ and $y$ be two integrable random variables on Probability space (X, $\Sigma$, $P$) such that $$E(X|Y) =_{a.s} Y$$ and $$E(Y|X) =_{a.s} X$$
Show that $$X=_{a.s} Y$$

The thing looks like a simple proof result, but I don't know how to move on after showing that$$\int_{B} Y = \int_{B} X$$ for all $B \in \sigma(x)$ and $B \in \sigma(y)$

Now any hint on how to proceed? Thank you so much in advance

Comment: "Seemingly trivial" is ridiculous, this is known for being an elaborate exercise on conditional expectations, usually proposed with some hints. Here is one: assume that $X$ and $Y$ are both square integrable.

Comment: @Did Thanks and I come back to this one with your hint but still get stuck..could you please provide more help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

- For every real number $c$, consider $u(c)=E[X-Y;Y\leqslant c\lt X]$. Use the hypothesis that $E[Y\mid X]=X$ almost surely to show that $u(c)=E[Y-X;c\lt X,c\lt Y]$.
- Deduce that, if furthermore $E[X\mid Y]=Y$ almost surely, then $u(c)=-E[Y-X;X\leqslant c\lt Y]$.
- Studying the sign of the LHS and the RHS, deduce from the above that $u(c)=0$.
- Let $v(c)=P[Y\leqslant c\lt X]$. Deduce from the above that $v(c)=0$ for every real number $c$.
- Show that $\int\limits_\mathbb Rv(c)\mathrm dc=E[(X-Y)^+]$.
- Deduce that $X\leqslant Y$ almost surely.
- Conclude.

Comment: I do understand most of the remaining steps, but don't get the first step at all. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @PhoemueX Sure. Define $w(c)=E[X-Y;c\lt X,c\lt Y]$, what is $u(c)+w(c)$?

Comment: Thank you very much. So you actually mean $u(c) = \mathbb{E}[Y -X; c < X, c < Y]$ and not $X-Y$?