# Prove that if $E[X|\sigma(Y)] = Y$ and $E[Y|\sigma(X)] = X$ then $X = Y$ almost surely.

Tags: probability

Prove that if  $E[X|\sigma(Y)] = Y$ and $E[Y|\sigma(X)] = X$ then $X = Y$ almost surely.
This is my idea:

By assumption, $Y = E[X|\sigma(Y)] = E\left\lbrack E[Y|\sigma(X)]|\sigma(Y)\right\rbrack$, and I would like to show that this equals $E[Y|\sigma(X)]$ which equals $X$.  If I can show that $E[Y|\sigma(X)]$ is $\sigma(Y)$ measurable, then the proof is finished.  But I am not sure how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a hint, you can try computing $E[(X-Y)^2]$.

Comment: Also, I find it easier to just use $E[X|Y]=Y$ and $E[Y|X]=X$.

Comment: Well, I guess my approach also assumes second moments are finite.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: Yes, it is a duplicate, but I don't think that the answer given there is correct.

Comment: @PhoemueX Try this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385109/question-about-conditional-expectation

Comment: Thanks Augustin for helping edit my question.  Thanks Michael and Byron for the help.  I think I understand it mostly.

Comment: Also @Michael your first hint about computing E[(X−Y)2]  is much shorter and simpler.   Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Michael That is much better than the answers given in the other questions!

Comment: @Michael Oh right, second moments aren't necessarily finite. Oh well. Can't use that, Ann Marie.